# Publishing with Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

Just got a laptop running Ubuntu and I need to publish brochures. I use Microsoft Publisher. Is there any software I can use that has the same or similar features to MS Publisher?

Answer (score 2):

A quick look your says that you are to choose between Scribus and LibreOffice Write/Draw. If those don't cut it, you may want to look into making a Windows virtual machine for Publisher.

Answer (score 2):

As for beginners Scribus is the best. Very simple and powerfull.